# In order for eval to work, I need to import a class I won't use. Is there a better way of doing it?

Tags: python, python-import

I have two classes. `Letter`:

```
class Letter:

    def __init__(self, text):
        self._text = text

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Letter('{}')".format(self._text)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(self, type(other)):
            return vars(self) == vars(other)
        return NotImplemented
```

And `Envelope`, which has a `Letter` object:

```
from letter import Letter


class Envelope:

    def __init__(self, letter):
        self._letter = letter

    @classmethod
    def template(cls):
        return cls(Letter('Kind regards'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Envelope({})'.format(self._letter)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(self, type(other)):
            return vars(self) == vars(other)
        return NotImplemented
```

Now in my unittest I have the following for `TestEnvelope`:

```
import unittest
from envelope import Envelope
from letter import Letter


class TestEnvelope(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_creation(self):
        envelope = Envelope.template()
        same = eval(repr(envelope))
        self.assertEqual(envelope, same)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

This eval will only work if I import `Letter`, but I'm not sure if this is the
right way of doing it because I'll have an unused import
[[./test_envelope.py:3:1: F401 'letter.Letter' imported but unused](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/error-codes.html)]

Otherwise, if I don't import `Letter` in the test, I get [NameError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#NameError):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 test_envelope.py line 9 in test_creation
   same = eval(repr(envelope))
 <string> line 1 in <module>

NameError: name 'Letter' is not defined
```

What should I do?

Comment: You could `eval(repr(envelope), {'Letter': Letter})`, but I’d just `self.assertEqual(repr(envelope), …)` with a string literal.

Comment: The import isn't really unused, but whatever linter is giving you that warning has no way of discerning that. I wouldn't worry about it

Comment: I'm afraid `self.assertEqual(repr(envelope), …)` would return some false positives. On the other hand `eval(repr(envelope), {'Letter': Letter})` raised `NameError` for Envelope, weird. What does that dict actually do? @Ryan

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that actually makes sense, thanks!

Comment: @ArthurZopellaro: What false positives? Are you testing `repr()` or  something else?

Comment: Let's say I add a new functionality that changes one of my internal attributes. If I just compare `repr()` to a literal representation, it might look like it's correct (but it wouldn't be). `x == eval(repr(x))` makes sure they're indeed equal